# Value error while fitting Decision Tree Classifier Keeping NaN values intact

Tags: python

I am trying to fit DT Classifier on data in which two columns has missing values. Since DT takes care of the missing values, I want to test the model without imputing any values i.e. by keeping missing values as NaN. But when I run the model, I get the value error,

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')
```

I have tried the below code:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')

#converting -999 to NAN
train_data.x14[train_data.x14==-999]=np.NaN
train_data.x15[train_data.x15==-999]=np.NaN

train_data = train_data.reset_index()

#defining x and y
x = train_data.iloc[:,1:18]
y = train_data.iloc[:,-1]
print("Sample x data\n", x.head(n=5))
print("Sample y data\n", y.head(n=5))

X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=0)
X_train = X_train.values
Y_train = Y_train.values

model = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10, 
                               min_samples_split=5,
                                       random_state=520)
                                       # class_weight='balanced')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to keep the `NaN` intact would be to drop them before you give the data to the classifier.

```
x = train_data.dropna().iloc[:,1:18]
y = train_data.dropna().iloc[:,-1]
```

Your training data (`x` and `y`) will not contain `NaN` (you have no choice), but at least your `DataFrame` an its missing values will remain intact (for whatever reason you want this to be).